# How to launch a chrome bookmark with Windows command line?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cmd

I am trying to open a bookmark saved in chrome using windows command line (or powershell).
The bookmark is not a URL but a javascript which I use to automate some task at destination website.
Can I trigger the entire event (chrome launch + bookmark open) using command line?
Or any other method using which I can schedule this task.

Answer (score 1):

How is your bookmarklet defined? It's a bit unclear, compare [Create Bookmarklets - The Right Way](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154)

In next example, `.js` and `.html` files are stored locally, both in the same folder. However, could be stored anywhere, compare [HTML `<script>` **`src`** Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_script_src.asp):

> *Syntax*:
>
> ```
> <script src="URL">
> ```
>
> Possible *URL* attribute values:
>
> - An *absolute URL* - points to another web site (like `src="http://www.example.com/example.js"`)
> - A *relative URL* - points to a file within a web site (like `src="/scripts/example.js"`)

**Files**: `dir /B /S 40460552.*`

```
d:\bat\SO\40460552.html
d:\bat\SO\40460552.js
```

**Javasript**: `type "D:\bat\SO\40460552.js"`

```
// JavaScript Document
document.write("Text from script");
alert( "script done" );
```

**HTML**: `type "D:\bat\SO\40460552.html"`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Text from page before script</p>

        <script src="40460552.js"></script>

        <p>Text from page after script</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**cmd**: use [`START` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

```
start "" chrome --allow-running-insecure-content "D:\bat\SO\40460552.html"
```